# MongoDB Count With Condition within Project with $eq

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'm trying to count my "$attendance.status" with aggregation mongodb.

I've get my data with relations. then i want to count by relation columns like 'present', 'off', etc.

code

```
Employee.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "Attendance",
          let: { employeeId: "$_id" },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $and: [
                  { $expr: { $eq: ["$employeeId", "$$employeeId"] } },
                  { isApproved: true },
                  {
                    createdAt: {
                      $gte: startOfMonth.toDate(),
                      $lte: endOfMonth.toDate(),
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          ],
          as: "attendance",
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          username: 1,
          name: 1,
          attendance: 1,
          present: { $sum: { $eq: ["$attendance.status", "present"] } },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

But why cannot count my column?

i use $eq, with $sum then count the result. but the result is 0

```
{
            "username": "Ethyl",
            "name": "Kuhn",
            "id": "614d43cde735f3e601dea165",
            "attendance": [
                {
                    "_id": "614d43cde735f3e601dea16f",
                    "status": "present",
                    "start": "2021-09-24T03:19:41.645Z",
                    "employeeId": "614d43cde735f3e601dea165",
                    "isApproved": true
                },
            ],
            "present": 0,
            "sick": 0,
            "off": 0,
        },
```

Comment: Use Project First and then use group.

Comment: I'v tried like this after project. but not work:( ```$group: { _id:"$attendance.status", count: { $sum: { $eq: ["$attendance.status", "present"] } }},``` still returning 0

Comment: yupz you are right. :( opss no other idea.

Comment: i think the problem with $eq.

Comment: I think so......